# Does GADM have level 2 population data availability for African countries

Tags: population, africa, gadm

I was wondering if GADM have level 2 population data availability for African countries (as many years as possible)?

If not, would anyone know other resources that may have?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: [World Bank](https://www.worldbank.org/en/home)?